# Print getcwd path

Tags: c, arrays, unix, getcwd

My instructions are pretty clear, but I'm doing it wrong, can you help correct my error?

Instructions: 
else if (“pwd”)
declare a char variable array of size MAX_PATH_LENGTH to hold the path do a getcwd
print the path

my code:

```
 }else if(strcmp(argv[0],"pwd")){
        char arr[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];
        char getcwd(arr,MAX_PATH_LENGTH);
        printf("cwd: %s",arr);
```

Comment: `char getcwd(arr,MAX_PATH_LENGTH);` => `getcwd(arr, MAX_PATH_LENGTH);`. Also you should check the return value before printing the value.

Comment: `if(strcmp(argv[0],"pwd"))` means "if the strings are unequal". And I wonder where `argv[0]` comes from. If it is an argument of `main` then `argv[0]` is the executable's name.

Comment: What do you intend to do at this line char getcwd(arr,MAX_PATH_LENGTH); ??

Comment: Please post code that actually compiles. The line `char getcwd(arr,MAX_PATH_LENGTH);` is a function declaration, that is missing the parameter types, not a call to the function.

Comment: thank you @willys that was my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strcmp returns an integer and not a boolean.

```
int strcmp (const char* str1, const char* str2);
```

It returns a 0 if the two strings are equal, so you should be checking the returned value in your if statement like this:

```
if(strcmp(argv[0],"pwd")==0)
```